# How to pass parameters to SurfaceView from main activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, parameters, parameter-passing, surfaceview

I need to draw a line diagram using surfaceview so from Main activity i will pass 2 parameters to surfaceview following this [link][1] solution

[1]: [Passing arguments to SurfaceView via Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834654/passing-arguments-to-surfaceview-via-constructor) but still my passed parameters are 0 inside surfaceview draw method, please help

MySurfaceView.java:
    private int len,theta;

```
public void setParameter(int length, int angle){
    this.len = length;
    this.theta = angle;
    System.out.println("inside setParameter, len: "+len+" ,theta: "+theta);
}
protected void drawSomething(Canvas canvas) {

    System.out.println("Inside drawSomething() , len: "+len+" ,theta: "+theta);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```

}
MainActivity.java

```
MySurfaceView myView = new MySurfaceView(MainActivity.this);
                    myView.setParameter(90,30);
                    myView.invalidate();
```

Values are printed only inside setParameter() not inside drawSomething(), i need to use those values inside drawSomething(),please help
Edited my code below,

```
public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}
private void init(){

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas(null);
            drawSomething(canvas);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                                   int format, int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }});
}
```

Comment: Where is drawSomething(Canvas canvas) called?

Comment: @andras drawSomething is called in init() method and init() is called in contructor, i added those code by editing my question. Inside init() also i tried to print those values but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Since `drawSomething(canvas)` is called in a callback, you cannot know if it will be called earlier or not than your next function `setParameter(int, int)`.

If you want to have the values available for `drawSomething(canvas)`, you have to pass them in the constructor of `MySurfaceView`, or extend the class `SurfaceHolder.Callback` and pass the value to those.

Comment: You create the view from code, so just create a constructor with `MySurfaceView(Context context, int length, int angle)`.

Comment: as per your suggestion i created constructor,public MySurfaceView(Context context,int length,int angle) {

        super(context);
        len = length;
        theta = angle;
        init(len,theta);
    }and called init() method with the passed parameters

Comment: But when i delete the other constructor with AttributeSet,public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }it throws the error 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]'

Comment: Which means, you have declared the view in the xml. That's not what you said though. Here is the answer you can follow in an xml case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8090772/4420543

Comment: yes i declared view in the xml as,<com.rd.sands.bluetooth.MySurfaceView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" /> in activity_main.xml, i read that link but still i am confused how to use the constructor, can you please help me

Comment: It will be very helpfull if you guide me how to pass paramaeters to MySyrfaceView from MainActivity since i declared the surfaceview in mainactivity xml file.I am stuck in this for more than a day,so please help

Comment: First, you do not call the constructor of the view, if you declare it in xml. Otherwise you are creating a different new view. Second, if you want to use custom attributes - the link I've sent you - you do not modifiy the default constructors, and then just use the constructor with the given `AttributeSet` and custom variable.

Comment: Now i created constructor, public MySurfaceView(Context context, int angle) {
        super(context);
        length = angle;
        init(length);
    }and called this from my activity as MySurfaceView myView = new MySurfaceView(getApplicationContext(),60);myView.invalidate(); Now i can get the value inside my init() method but inside init() method i dont know how to pass that value to callback drawSomething() method

Comment: how to get that value inside surfaceCreated() method

Comment: do you know answer for my question which is posted in below link, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322864/how-to-reset-layout-back-to-original-state-after-zooming-ends" no one answered for this,if you know please help

Comment: @Annie I am not familiar with the library you asked about.

Comment: not with the particular library, Now i applied zooming for linearlayout only, i dont know how to reset the layout back to original state from zooming when user double tap